# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when uploading code to STM32

Tags: java, arduino, stm32

I'm getting the following error when trying to upload code to a STM32 "Bluepill" board using the `STM32duino Bootloader` aka `DFU` method:

```
maple_loader v0.1
Resetting to bootloader via DTR pulse
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=1720, tid=0x0000000000000c98
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
```

This doesn't happen in another one of my computers. What's happening?

Comment: Where is the **programming** question? How to configure and use IDE is off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a strange fix.

Had to **change the path to the Java binary to point to the provided version inside Arduino installation folder**.

This is done through **Environment Variables** in Windows Control panel. You may also need to uninstall any other Java versions if you have any.

Comment: I have the same exact issue, but neither solution works for me. Do you know why this solution worked for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue as well and I fixed it by uninstalling both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Java and reinstalling only the 64-bit version.
I have not tested whether installing the 32-bit version again will cause the issue.